# Strace with writev() function in Linux, what does the '@', '2w', and '240K' represent in the data?

Tags: c, linux, strace

I have an strace of my program that interacts with USB, and I am wondering what the following write command tells me.  I understand the writev iovec structure consists of the data array pointer followed by the length, but what does the `"@\10\335 \320\2w\4\240K\252\0\7"` in the data array denote?  I'm particularly wondering what the @ symbol, 2w, and 240K means as those are not hex data values as I would expect them to be.

I'm running on Linux and here is the writev line:

```
writev(6, [{"@\10\335 \320\2w\4\240K\252\0\7", 13}, {"\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4", 8}], 2) = 21
```

Comment: "@" is an "@". "2w" is part of the two bytes "\2w". "240K" is part of the two bytes "\240K".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, so it just is a direct ASCII translation?

Comment: For the parts in printable ASCII, sure.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, also, doesn't the 13 represent the size in bytes of the data packet?  Also, if you translate 240K in ascii to hex, it is 4 bytes...can you further explain this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not "240K", it's "\240K". The backslash makes all the difference in the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [man page of `writev`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/writev):

```
ssize_t readv(int fd, const struct iovec *iov, int iovcnt);
```

That is, the second argument is an array of size the value of the third argument (`2` in your case) elements of type `struct iovec`.

When `strace` prints those it *octal* escapes unprintable characters but displays all other exactly as they can be printed. Hence, `@` is just the byte corresponding to `@`, `K` is the byte corresponding to `K` and so on.

---

Answering your questions in the comment, another look at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/writev) shows

```
struct iovec {
    void  *iov_base;    /* Starting address */
    size_t iov_len;     /* Number of bytes to transfer */
};
```

Which means that `{"@\10\335 \320\2w\4\240K\252\0\7", 13}` is to be read as `iov_len = 13` and `iov_base` is a memory area containing the bytes printed as `@\10\335 \320\2w\4\240K\252\0\7`. Fire up `gdb` if you want to see the binary values:

```
[mihai@winterfell 1]$ gdb -q
(gdb) p/x "@\10\335 \320\2w\4\240K\252\0\7"
$1 = {0x40, 0x8, 0xdd, 0x20, 0xd0, 0x2, 0x77, 0x4, 0xa0, 0x4b, 0xaa, 0x0, 0x7, 0x0}
```

Where the last `0x0` is the null terminator of the string and should be ignored.